# Overload Resolution With Templates

Tags: c++

Recently, I've had a problem with overload resolution of template overloads not behaving as I expect. I've looked up the overload resolution rules and haven't found anything regarding my issue so if anyone could refer me or explain why it behaves the way it does I would really appreciate it.

Consider this piece of code:

```
template<unsigned int max_size>
void foo(char (& arr)[max_size], unsigned int used_size) {}

void foo(char arr[], unsigned int size) {}

template<unsigned int max_size>
void boo(const char (& arr)[max_size], unsigned int used_size) {}

void boo(const char arr[], unsigned int size) {}

main()
{
    char arr[10];

    foo(arr, 10); // calls second foo
    boo(arr, 10); // calls first boo
}
```

I can't figure out why the const makes a difference in the choice of function in the way it does. I have tried compiling with both g++ and clang but it doesn't make a difference.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers!

Comment: Are you sure? Seems that the both calls should invoke second versions.

Comment: Can't duplicate. http://ideone.com/srdpje.

Comment: @Edgar - No, I'm not sure.  :-) I can explain the first case, but the second one is too complicated for me.

Comment: @RSahu yeah, I think that in both cases second versions will be invoked just because arrays decays to pointers and there's no matter if the size of array is declared, a simple function matches better than template.

Comment: @BoPersson I tested both with g++ and clang and 2-nd versions were called. Looks like the question is not correct.

Comment: @Edgar - Same with VS2015, so me having a hard time with case 2 might be because the assumption is incorrect. :-)

Comment: Please add compiler/os details. Maybe someone can track it down, if the behavior is indeed as you describe.

Comment: The only way I could get a template to be a better match (g++ 6.1) was if I changed `boo` to take a reference to array of const, i.e. `const char (&arr)[max_size]`, as first argument.  (The non-const equivalent for `foo` has no effect).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because every compiler I've tried does the right thing - calls the 2nd overload in both cases. As it stands, the issue is non-reproducible and hence not an MCVE.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the mistake - in both first iterations it was supposed to be reference to array. Sorry!